# How to create dynamic bracket borders around content?

Tags: css, dynamic, border

I'm trying to add this gray bracket to the right of a list. I tried playing around with borders on the div around the each item, but the items are separated by a few other tags and margin space top and bottom, also I don't know how to get only part of a top border showing. I need the brackets to expand and stay aligned if a selected item is expanded.

Any CSS recommendations?

[image]

This is where I'm at now https://jsfiddle.net/ux9dxoa9/

```
.item {


 float: left;
      clear:left;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.other_div{
    float: left;
  padding: 18px 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Any CSS we might suggest is entirely dependant upon your HTML; so first: we need to see your [mcve] code, and your best attempt at solving your own problem, with an explanation of how it failed.

Comment: where's the code that you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo elements

```css
* {
  margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.outer, .outer > li {
  position: relative;
}

.outer > li {
  padding: 1em;
}

.outer:before, .outer:after, .outer > li:not(:first-child):before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: .5em;
  height: 1px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.outer:before, .outer:after, .outer > li:before, .outer > li:after {
  right: 0;
}

.outer:before, .outer > li:before {
  top: 0;
}

.outer:after, .outer > li:after {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="outer">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>nested
    <ul>
      <li>nested</li>
      <li>nested</li>
      <li>nested</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice, Thank you. Though I'm not able to wrap the items horizontally because there is another div between each item that is floated left